# Compile on a per-chapter basis, from within subfile

Tags: external-files

My current project has many chapters, which are included via `\input{chapters/chapter1.tex}` from the main document. (The actual setup is a little more complex, but close enough.)

When I am editing `chapter1.tex`, I can trigger a full rebuild from within the file, having added

```
% !TeX root = ../main.tex
```

to it. That said, this already takes a few minutes and will only get worse; it would suffice to compile `chapter1.tex` for now, i.e. while working on it.

Can you think of a good way to trigger such a partial compilation from within `chapter1.tex`? Using `\include` (as opposed to `\input`) in `main.tex` is not an option for this project, and `main.tex` must remain fundamentally unchanged, so I can't comment out parts there on the fly. Adding a full preamble to `chapter1.tex` would be possible, I suppose, but this alls gets input into `main.tex` … Thoughts?

Comment: some editors will do this on the fly but classically you can set the TeX root comment to be a small wrapper document that has a preamble and inputs just the one chapter so you need one extra file per chapter but they are static files you don't need to edit once set up

Comment: So basically a dummy.tex, which is a copy of main.tex but ony includes the one chapter? I have 100+ “chapters”, but if that's what it takes …

Comment: emacs will let you tex a file (or even just a marked region) constructing a wrapper from the main document preamble on the fly, but not everyone uses emacs editor

Comment: I am more of a vi man myself :-) But full disclosure: these days Sublime covers all my needs. I appreciate your thoughts, though (and not just in this thread.)

Comment: Have you considered the `subfiles` package? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/subfiles

Comment: I have not, simply because I was unaware of its existence. I am looking into it.

Comment: Unfortunately `subfiles` turned out not to be a drop-in solution for me. In theory it sounds great and pretty much what I've been looking for. In practice, I haven't been able to make it work yet. I will have to try with a reduced set of files and study logs a little more carefully when time permits. Thanks for pointing this package out to me, though!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [`subfiles`](https://ctan.org/pkg/subfiles?lang=en)-structure. The chapterX.tex are stored in a subdirectory called »chapters«.

Main.tex:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\providecommand{\main}{.}

\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\subfile{chapters/chapter1}
\subfile{chapters/chapter2}

\end{document}
```

chapter1.tex:

```
\providecommand{\main}{..}

\documentclass[../main]{subfiles}

\begin{document}

\chapter{One}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: I appreciate your efforts. I'll give it a go when I get the time in the next few days.